# Binding some Vue code to existing, server-side generated HTML

Tags: vue.js

I have an old-style, multiple-page website, with a multiple steps checkout process. This all works with JS disabled, and it is critical that it keeps doing so.

The checkout form has no JS at all, at the moment, and I'd like to improve it progressively (eg. dynamically showing or hiding fields, doing live validation, etc...).

I have already wrapped the entire website with an #app div, and I mounted a Vue instance to it. Then I created a few components which work correctly (but are not critical, so if JS is disabled then the whole thing keeps working and the components are just empty).

Now I have a long checkout form which is generated server-side (say: `<form id='address-form'>`).

The best course would be to put it into a component (say `<checkout-form`>) and use it. I can't do this, because 1) the form is generated server-side 2) it needs to work without JS.

Ideally, I would love to create a component with no template, and attach it to the existing HTML.

Is this even possible?

**Edit**: continuing to dig the Internet, I found [this tutorial](https://blog.kaliop.com/en/blog/2018/08/22/prerendered-and-server-side-rendered-forms-in-vue-js/). This is exactly my problem, but if this is the only way to do it, then I will revert to JQuery :) Manually duplicating the entire HTML (one server side, the other in Vue) is definitely not a good idea.

Comment: You might have some success using Nuxt to generate static apps,though it can be tricky if you want to do data-binding etc: https://nuxtjs.org/guide

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely look into this when starting a new project. But putting this inside an existing large PHP codebase would probably require A LOT of work :-)